# when to use data() and when to use setup() in vue3?

Tags: vuejs3

I am still new to Vue and when I was using vue 2, I always used this:

```
data() {
        return {
           ....
        }
}
methods: {
  ....
}
```

but now I see a lot of docs with

```
setup() {
 const .....
 return { ... }

}
```

are these essentially the same? when would be a use case for data() vs setup()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Vue.js 2 you have been using the so-called `Options API`. Vue.js 3 comes with the `Composition API` that can be used instead of the `Options API`.

Both ways are essentially the same and you can go with either one. However, you should understand the difference (for example, `this` doesn't refer to the component in the `setup()` method and you shouldn't use it).

The `Composition API` approach is better for various reasons explained in detail [in the official FAQ](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html). In short, it provides:

- Better Logic Reuse
- More Flexible Code Organization
- Better Type Inference
- Smaller Production Bundle and Less Overhead

You can still use the `Options API`, it won't be deprecated and is perfectly suitable for smaller projects.

I highly suggest reading this article about it: [Why I Love Vue 3's Composition API](https://mokkapps.de/blog/why-i-love-vue-3-s-composition-api/).

Comment: This really helped, thanks